# Get workflow transitions in Jira Python

Tags: python-3.x, jira, python-jira

How to get all the status/transition in Jira API ?

http://example.com/rest/api/2/workflow/ returns

```
[{"name":"jira","description":"The default JIRA workflow.","steps":5,"default":true}]
```

No id is present in the output, so not able to get workflow details/components.

http://example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/PROJ-1/transitions provides only issue specific transition, I need future transitions too.

Any pointer or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Transitions are specific for project and issue type. So you want to see all statuses in Jira ?

Comment: I want workflow specific statuses.

Comment: I think the only option is `http://example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/PROJ-1/transitions` . As you mentioned, it gives issue specific transitions but those should be all statuses that issue can be in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing All JIRA Transitions via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928540/listing-all-jira-transitions-via-api)

Answer (score 0):

I can't mark question as duplicated, so here is [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047546/2562686):

You can get all transitions for project with [/rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/statuses](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-getAllStatuses) endpoint. Here is response example, look at "statuses" array:

```
[
    {
        "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/issueType/3",
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Task",
        "subtask": false,
        "statuses": [
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/status/10000",
                "description": "The issue is currently being worked on.",
                "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8090/jira/images/icons/progress.gif",
                "name": "In Progress",
                "id": "10000"
            },
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/status/5",
                "description": "The issue is closed.",
                "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8090/jira/images/icons/closed.gif",
                "name": "Closed",
                "id": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: There can be 10 statuses in my jira Instance, but my workflow might be having only 3 statuses like Open, In progress and Complete. I want to know workflow associated statuses.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the workflow, you can get all of its transitions with:

`GET /rest/api/2/workflow/search?workflowName={workflow_name}&expand=transitions`

See https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-workflows/#api-rest-api-2-workflow-search-get for more details.

However, if all you have is an `issue_key`, how do you find all transitions (not just the ones available based on its status)?  There are three steps:

1. Get the issue's `project_id` and `issue_type_id`

- `GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issue_key}`
- `project_id = issue.fields.project.id`
- `issue_type_id = issue.fields.issuetype.id`

2. Get the workflow name associated with the issue type from the project's workflow scheme

- `GET /rest/api/2/workflowshceme/project?projectId={project_id}`
- `workflow_name = values[0].workflowScheme.issueTypeMappings[{issue_type_id}]`

3. Now at last we can get the transitions

- `GET /rest/api/2/workflow/search?workflowName={workflow_name}&expand=transitions`

Here is all of that in python:

```
import sys
import requests
import json
# NOTE: jira_integration encapsulates how we connect to our Jira account
#       adapt this script as you see fit
from jira_integration import JIRA_API_BASE_URL, JIRA_AUTH_HEADERS


def getFromJira(url_path):
    response = requests.get(f'{JIRA_API_BASE_URL}{url_path}', headers=JIRA_AUTH_HEADERS)
    
    if not response.status_code  == 200:
        raise RuntimeError(f'getFromJira() was not successful: {response.status_code} {response.reason}\n{response.json()}') 
    
    return response.json()


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        issue_key = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        print('Please provide the issue key')
        return

    try:
        # Step 1
        issue = getFromJira(f'/rest/api/2/issue/{issue_key}')
        project_id = issue['fields']['project']['id']
        issue_type_id = issue['fields']['issuetype']['id']

        # Step 2
        search_results = getFromJira(f'/rest/api/2/workflowscheme/project?projectId={project_id}')
        workflow_scheme_project_association = search_results['values'][0]
        workflow_name = workflow_scheme_project_association['workflowScheme']['issueTypeMappings'][issue_type_id]

        # Step 3
        search_results = getFromJira(f'/rest/api/2/workflow/search?workflowName={workflow_name}&expand=transitions')
        transitions = search_results['values'][0]

        print(json.dumps(transitions, indent=4))
        
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```